# Self Signed Certificate in Android

Tags: android, certificate, ssl-certificate, self-signed, httpsurlconnection

I am able to use Self-signed certificate, which I created using openssl.

The only problem I get while using the certificate in my `HttpsURLConnection` is of HostnameVerifier.

If I supply my own HostnameVerifier, which always `return true` like :

```
HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    };
```

in

```
urlConnection.setHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
```

it works.

Is there any way we can provide verification for our own host and not true for all ?

AND

Will `HostnameVerifier` work for local network (local IPs) also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume your server app is hosting inside a server machine which has a server certificate in which `"Issued to"` is `"localhost"`, for example. Then, inside **`verify`** method you can verify `"localhost"`.

```
HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        HostnameVerifier hv =
            HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
        return hv.verify("localhost", session);
    }
};
```